# App is rejected because of bug on iPad running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Apple send me reject message.

> "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks."

I already checked app on iPad running iOS 9.2.1, but I didn't get any bugs.
What to do for resubmitting my app?

Comment: Can you please post latter part of the reviewers message? there are should be some more.

Comment: you need to set a Internet available check on each request or API call. then resubmit

Comment: 2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
2.2 Details

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
is it right?